# Python nested while-loop doesn't increment as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, increment, pixelate

I'm writing a function in Python to pixelate an image, but for some reason xx and x doesn't increment. Both variables keep the value 0 throughout and nothing happens.

```
xx = 0
yy = 0

while xx < width:
    while yy < height:
        print ("---", xx, yy)
        offsetX = xx + block_size_half
        offsetY = yy + block_size_half

        while (xx + offsetX >= width):
            offsetX -= 1
        while (yy + offsetY >= height):
            offsetY -= 1

        r, g, b = matrix[xx + offsetX][yy + offsetY]

        x = xx
        y = yy
        while x < xx + block_size and x < width:
            while y < yy + block_size and y < height:
                print (x, y)
                matrix[x][y] = (r, g, b)
                y += 1

            x += 1

        yy += block_size

    xx += block_size
```

Thanks to @Elazar for help! Here is the entire working function:

```
def pixelate(matrix, block_size):
    width = len(matrix)
    height = len(matrix[0])
    block_size_half = int(block_size / 2)

    for xx in range(0, width, block_size):
        for yy in range(0, height, block_size):

            offsetX = min(xx + block_size_half, width - 1)
            offsetY = min(yy + block_size_half, height - 1)

            r, g, b = matrix[offsetX][offsetY]

            for x in range(xx, min(xx + block_size, width)):
                for y in range(yy, min(yy + block_size, height)):
                    matrix[x][y] = (r, g, b)
```

I got inspiration for the algorithm from this C# implementation:
http://notes.ericwillis.com/2009/11/pixelate-an-image-with-csharp/

Comment: I am not sure but check for indentation problem

Comment: maybe `block_size == 0` ?

Comment: GrijeshChauhan:  I tried to see if anything was wrong with the indentation, but couldn't find anything.
Elazar: shouldn't be the problem, since yy and y incremented correctly. Thanks for the answer below!

Comment: better: `block_size_half = block_size // 2`. it is simple enough to be ommitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see no reason why you wouldn't use `xrange()` (or `range()`)

```
for xx in range(0, width, block_size):
    for yy in range(0, height, block_size):
        ...
```

[EDIT]

rewriting the whole example, you will get something like:

```
for xx in range(0, width, block_size):
    for yy in range(0, height, block_size):
        print ("---", xx, yy)
        offsetX = min(width, xx + block_size_half)
        offsetY = min(height, yy + block_size_half)

        r, g, b = matrix[xx + offsetX][yy + offsetY]

        for x in range(xx, min(xx + block_size, width)):
            for y in range(yy, min(yy + block_size, height)):
                print (x, y)
                matrix[x][y] = (r, g, b)
```

which can probably get even shorter.

Comment: Thank you! :)
Seems like xrange() isn't part of Python 3.x
Note that offsetX/Y in the code is an offset within the current block of pixels (i.e. within the two outer loops). I'll post the entire method so it makes sense.